# What would the correct Latin term be for 'most wise robot' or 'very wise android'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm working on a plot for a sequel to my children's musical Granny Galactica.  It will be a 'grown-up' sequel set 40 years after the first one, and will include a character called Nettlebot - a robot which achieves super-intelligence combined with a deep understanding of and respect for humanity.  I'd like her to represent the first of an artificial 'species' with a moniker like 'roboticus sapientissimus' but my Latin skills are not good enough to come up with a convincing term.  Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just for your information, there is also a neologistic word for a robot, **robotum**, directly Latinized from English. But such words are avoided, I think, by many modern Latin users of good Latinity, however.

Answer (score 8):

For the adjective, *sapientissimus, -ma, -mum* conveys 'most wise' or 'very wise'. The words "robot" and "android" have no exact equivalent in Classical Latin, but Greek *αὐτόματον* (literally 'self-acting', Latinized as *automatum*; you could also simply transliterate it directly from the Greek form as *automaton*) had a similar sense, being used to refer to mechanical puppets. You could perhaps then use "*Automatum sapientissimum*" or "*Automaton sapientissimum*" as fake species name (with *Automatum/-on* capitalized as a mock-genus name, and *sapientissimum* as a mock-specific name).

Answer (score 3):

The term ανδροειδης, Latinized as androīdēs, also describes 'something like a man', and is of course the translation for 'android' into Modern Greek, according to IATE